# How to insert my data in SPSS for Roc curve

Tags: spss, roc

I want to draw a roc curve in SPSS and I don't know how to insert my data in SPSS.
The data I have are:

```
             Patients     Healthy with
             with AIDS    ELISA below
             with ELISA   the 
             above the    absorbance
 ELISA       absorbance   value        Sp       Se
absorbance   
<2           88            0           0.000    1.000
2.5          86            202         0.680    0.977
3.5          79            275         0.926    0.898
4.5          72            290         0.976    0.818
5.5          57            293         0.987    0.648
9            21            295         0.993    0.239
<12          0             297         1.000    0.000
```

Comment: In most programs you have a score, and a criterion (which is 0, 1).  I can't understand your question though.

Comment: +1 to @JeremyMiles. Are you simply asking how to draw an ROC curve based on the predictions in one of the latter columns?

Answer (score 2):

I've voted as off-topic for this site since it seems to just be about programming. But as an illustration of using the aggregate data in SPSS's `ROC` procedure is below. In a nutshell you have to reshape the data so the positive and negative class counts are in one column, and then weight the data.

```
DATA LIST FREE / Absorbance Negative Positive Sp Se.
BEGIN DATA
2           88            0           0.000    1.000
2.5          86            202         0.680    0.977
3.5          79            275         0.926    0.898
4.5          72            290         0.976    0.818
5.5          57            293         0.987    0.648
9            21            295         0.993    0.239
12          0             297         1.000    0.000
END DATA.

VARSTOCASES /MAKE Weight FROM Negative Positive
            /INDEX Outcome.
WEIGHT BY Weight.

ROC Absorbance BY Outcome (2)
  /PLOT CURVE(REFERENCE)
  /PRINT SE COORDINATES.
```

[image]

If you have the unaggregated data I have a [blog post](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/roc-and-precision-recall-curves-in-spss/) showing how to calculate the specificity, sensitivity and the precision for the dataset.